# Выровнять текст колонки jTable по середине

Tags: java, swing

Как можно выровнять значения в колонках JTable по середине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

центрировать все столбцы со строковыми данными

```
    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRend = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRend.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRend);
```

Comment: Только в setDefaultRenderer нужно centerRend указать